# RedirectFromLoginPage or Response.Redirect do not work with IIS10

Tags: webforms, forms-authentication, iis-10

We have a couple of legacy WebForm apps using FormsAuthentication that we are updating to the latest .NET version and moving from Server 2008 R2 to Server 2016.

After successfully logging in the user is correctly forwarded to the secure section of the app, both in the existing version of the app (.NET 4.5.1) and in debug (.NET 4.6.1), but when deployed on the server the user can authenticate but forwarding fails - it will sit at the login page until the session timeout pop-up appears..

Authentication is

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(vUserName.ToString, False)
```

In the original app redirection is

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(vUserName, False)
```

We have also tried

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(vUserID, False), False)
```

Both work in debug (IIS 7) but neither work as deployed in IIS 10

Deployment does enable Forms Authentication for that site... I'm guessing they changed something in IIS 10, but can't figure it out...

Thanks

Comment: Does your server name has an underscore character? Also, in your web.config do you have the proper <system.web>
   <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web> ? Is this happening in all broswers?

Comment: No underscores in the server name - system.web has <authentication mode="Forms"> and <forms name="SecureLogin" loginUrl="Secure/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="Default"/> - not tested in other browsers yet - will give that a try :-)

Comment: Tried with Edge, Chrome and IE11 - exactly the same, just posts back to the login page

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the cookie somehow it's not getting stored..

Comment: It was AjaxControlToolkit causing the problem - thank you for taking the time to assist :-)

Answer (score 0):

I updated 33 NuGet packages, and it threw the toys out over ToolkitScriptManager (removed in v15.1 https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager)

Replaced all incidents of ToolkitScriptManager with ScriptManager and it now runs on IIS 10 - Server 2016